# How to get the same string irrespective having leading zero or not in Sequelize nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I would like to know how to find the string exists in database using Sequelize nodejs

I have the object, should check code and unit are same then retrieve it.

If i pass the unit number (`02`) with leading 0, it returns empty, as it finds exact match. fails to fetch like `2` which exists in db

```
var obj ={
  code: '123',
  unit: '02'
}



tried


Model.findOne({ 
   where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          { addressPostalCode: obj.code },
          { addressUnit: obj.unit }
        ]
      };
 })
```

Comment: What is the column type in the database for `addressUnit`? If it's a string, then `'02'` is not the same string as `'2'`, just like `'apple'` is not the same string as `'banana'`.  Where is the leading zero coming from?

Comment: @Pointy thanks for reply, i pass as object as a parameter to search and fetch records from db, is there a any way to get records

Comment: @Pointy i tried using `like`, `regex` but doesnt work

Comment: He is asking you what the type of the field is in the database, If it's a string your going to have to search for both using `$or`   , `{ addressUnit: $or: ['2','02']}`

Comment: Maybe you can consider using sqlite3 json functions: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: What regex did you try?.   I don't use Sequelize, but I've a feeling `regex` potentially will have some performance issues on db's that don't have a way of indexing regex's searches.   So it still might be an idea to keep with `$or`

Comment: @Keith its varchar type, { addressUnit: [Op.regex]: /^\d{1,45}$/ }

Comment: @Keith the search parameter is dynamic, and cannot directly pass it as static input

Comment: I'm not saying you do pass it as static.  You can of course replace the `['2', '02']` with code that creates the array.

Comment: Your regex is saying search for any number that is 1 to 45 chars long.   But what you really want to do is.  1. remove the pre-zero from the search, and then a regex like -> `^0*2$` would make more sense..  That regex will then search for anything that ends with 2, and has any number of 0's in front.

Comment: If your id values are always numeric (in the database) even though they are for some reason stored as strings, you could use type casting in the query predicate to force them to be compared as integers. However, if the database column may contain non-numeric id values, then the right thing to do is make sure that your search parameters are the *correct* strings. Whatever is putting the 0 in front of `'02'` is the thing that should be fixed.